# How to verify a password on Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I want verify the existing password for a user (to allow them to change their password).

I thought to go the following route but ran into the problem that the hashed password always shows up as a different hash.  I am using      `UserPasswordHasherInterface`.

```
$hashedOldPassword = $passwordHasher->hashPassword(
        $user,
        $data['oldPassword']
    );

if ($hashedOldPassword === $user->getPassword()) {
    setNewPassword();
}
```

Comment: You want to change your password if the user enters the old password? Sorry, that's not understandable.

Comment: Ok sorry, i want check old password is correct and set new password

Answer (score 11):

To verify a password you do not rehash it. Each time you call `hashPassword()` you'll get a different hash, because the hashing algorithm introduces a random [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) for security.

But that interface includes a much more convenient `isPasswordValid()` method.

```
function isPasswordValid(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $plainPassword): bool
```

So simply do:

```
if (!$passwordHasher->isPasswordValid($user, $oldPassword)) {
   // error, you can't change your password 
   // throw exception or return, etc.
}

// no error, let them continue.
```